# ngx-datatable hidden Colum ANGULAR8

Tags: angular

I have a table with ngx-datatable, but I would like the created_at column to be hidden just to be used with filter and nothing else .. does anyone know how to hide this column?
Below is the code.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { companyDB } from '../../../shared/data/tables/company';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-professores',
  templateUrl: './professores.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./professores.component.scss']
})
export class ProfessoresComponent implements OnInit {

    public company = [];
    public right_side_bar: boolean;
    public columns = [
        {name:'Codigo Registro'},
        {name:'Nome completo'},
        {name:'Cidade Estado'},
        {name:'Macroareas'},
        {name:'Qtd. cursos'},
        {name:'Data fim ultimo curso'},
        {name:'Qtd. cursos cancelados'},
        {name:'Avaliacao media'},
        {name:'Hora aula'},
        {prop: 'created_at', name: 'Data de cadastro'} // that is the column
    ]
```

My component.html

```html
    <div class="card-body custom-datatable material expandable">
                    <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [rows]="company"
                        [columns]="columns" [columnMode]="'force'"
                        [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [limit]="10">
                    </ngx-datatable>
                </div>
```

[image]

Does anyone know which property could be used to perform this action. thankful

Comment: Use CSS to hide the last column of the table.

Comment: Keep the html template and remove it from the columns list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a property to hide the column after looking into the Github issues. Use CSS to hide the last column of each row:

```
::ng-deep tr td:last-child {
  display: none:
}
```

And do the same with `th`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use a .filter on the ngOnInit() function, like so:

```
this.columns = this.columns.filter(x => x.prop !== 'created_at');
```